# How do you create a new GUID in C++ in WinRT?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

What is the equivalent of the C# method [Guid.NewGuid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) in C++ WinRT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you look for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
CoCreateGuid();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing a Windows Store application (also known as Metro Style) you will have to use [CoCreateGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), since [UuidCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is only available for Desktop applications.

From MSDN:
**CoCreateGuid:**

> Applies to: desktop apps | Windows Store apps 
>   Creates a GUID, a unique
>   128-bit integer used for CLSIDs and interface identifiers.

```
HRESULT CoCreateGuid(  _Out_  GUID *pguid );
```

**UuidCreate:**

> Applies to: desktop apps only

Answer (score 2):

I know jack about Windows 8, but if you still have access to the regular Win32/64 APIs you can use a number of mechanics for this. `UuidCreate`() from the rpcrt4 library is one, `CoCreateGuid`() from the oleaut lib is another (which just forwards to the former). The latter has the nicety of at last dropping your result in a GUID struct directly.